# Is it possible to limit SSH client users to connect ONLY if I manually type the key into the SSH Server?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

So basically I want to get a more secure way to ssh into my server, because it is located in a very big LAN. I tried using firewall to only allow certain IP's into it, it works, but someone could manually change the IP to the one that is allowed un the UFW.

What I want is that if someone wants to log in the SSH I, as a server, will have to manually input the client's key into the server.

Comment: What do you mean by "manually inputting"? Disable the ability to do automated key deployment with `ssh-copy-id`, disable the ability for the users to add/update their keys?

Answer (score 1):

> What I want is that if someone wants to log in the SSH I, as a server, will have to manually input the client's key into the server.

That's basically what [key based authentication](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssh-key-based-authentication-on-a-linux-server) does.

You add a key (or multiple keys) per user that's allowed to connect. The keys are large cryptographic secrets, that's *totally* unfeasible to brute force. Someone without the key is unable to authenticate.

This is perfectly acceptable to servers exposed to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to really control access disable password based logins and only allow access with a private key.

If you use a password protected private key that only you have access to then they will not be able to login no matter what IP address they use.

You can disable password based login by editing the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file and settings `ChallengeResponseAuthentication`, `PasswordAuthentication` and `UsePAM` to `no`  (more details [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-disable-ssh-password-login-on-linux/)). You should only do this one you have properly setup and tested using ssh keys to login so you don't lock yourself out of the machine.